# Draw text at center

Tags: c#, forms

Which is the best way to drawString at the center of a rectangleF? Text font size can be reduced to fit it. In most case the Text is too big to fit with a given font so have to reduce the font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is working for me know. This is what I did

```
Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Text, Font);
float presentFontSize = Font.Size;
Font newFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily, presentFontSize, Font.Style);
while ((textSize.Width>textBoundary.Width || textSize.Height > textBoundary.Height) && presentFontSize-0.2F>0)
{
   presentFontSize -= 0.2F;
   newFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily,presentFontSize,Font.Style);
   textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(ButtonText, newFont);
}
stringFormat sf;
sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
e.Graphics.DrawString(Text,newFont,Brushes.Black,textBoundary, sf);
```

Comment: I saw that you had posted your working solution when I posted my version, but I let mine stay since it is more efficient (gets the font size without looping) and also I think that your code might leak memory, creating many font objects but not calling Dispose on them.

Comment: What is value of 'textBoundary' parameter ? Please declare and initialize it.

Comment: OKAY I GOT IT. textBoundary is created as below               String imgsrc="PATH OF IMAGE FILE ON DISK";
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imgsrc));
RectangleF textBoundary = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height - 30);

Comment: Update the answer to include textboundry!

Answer (score 16):

This code centers the text horizontally and vertically:

```
stringFormat sf;
sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
grp.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Black, rectf, sf);
```

Comment: what about reducing the font size?

Answer (score 11):

I played around with it a bit and found this solution (assuming that the `RectangleF rect` and `string text` are already defined):

```
StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat()
{
    Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
    LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
};

using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
{
    SizeF s = g.MeasureString(text, this.Font);
    float fontScale = Math.Max(s.Width / rect.Width, s.Height / rect.Height);
    using (Font font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, this.Font.SizeInPoints / fontScale, GraphicsUnit.Point))
    {
        g.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Black, rect, stringFormat);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Determine the size of the text to be drawn and then determine the offset for the start of the string from the centre of rectangleF and draw it.

Answer (score 0):

Get width/2 and height/2 of the rectangle, then using System.Graphics.MeasureString to get the dimensions of your string, again half them and subtract from your earlier width/height values and you end up with the X,Y coordinate to draw your string at in order for it to be centered.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to use :)

```
    public static void DrawStringCenter(Image image, string s, Font font, Color color, RectangleF layoutRectangle)
    {
        var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);

        var brush = new SolidBrush(color);

        var format = new StringFormat
        {
            Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
            LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        };

        graphics.DrawString(s, font, brush, layoutRectangle, format);
    }
```